# Reading large XML document to generate array of XML nodes in Powershell?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, powershell

I have code that loads an XML document, performs a `$xmlDoc.SelectNodes($XPath)` and then `foreach($node in $nodes)` pokes the XML as a string into a table.

This code works fine on files of ca. 100KB with 10 records.

However, I have a file that is ca. 100MB and ca. 50k records and the code just hangs at `$xmlDoc =[xml](gc $xmlpath)` (and uses all available system memory). Is there a better way to generate my array `$nodes` without first parsing the entire XML document?

```
# Loads xml document
$xmlpath = $filepath
$xmlDoc =[xml](gc $xmlpath)
$nodes = $xmlDoc.SelectNodes('//root') #One element per record in SQL

...

$SqlQuery = @"
INSERT INTO {0} VALUES ({1})
"@

....

foreach($node in $nodes) 
{ 
$StringWriter = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter 
$XmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter $StringWriter 
$XmlWriter.Formatting = "None" 
$XmlWriter.Flush() 
$StringWriter.Flush() 
$node.WriteTo($XmlWriter) 
#data content (for this quote)
$Pxml = "`'"+$StringWriter.ToString()+"`'"

#Write to database
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = [string]::Format($sqlquery, $tableName, $Pxml)
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()
}
```

The XMl document has structure:

```
<xml>
  <root>
   ...
  </root>
  <root>
   ...
  </root>
</xml>
```

and the resultant strings are of form:

```
<root>
 ...
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stephap/archive/2009/05/27/choking-on-very-large-xml-files.aspx?Redirected=true) as a basis, try the code below. The `$object` should contain your root object

```
$object= @()
type "$filepath" | %{
  if($_.trim() -eq "<root>") {
    $object= @()
    $object+= $_
  }
  elseif($_.trim() -eq "</root>"){
    $object+= $_
    #call the code within your foreach($node in $nodes) {} section here
  } else {
    $object+= $_
  }
 }
```

Comment: This produced the desired result almost straight out of the can.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, XML parsing requires the complete file to be in memory. Try to use a more efficient .Net method of reading the content. The following should run a lot faster and may use less memory, because it saves the content as a string-array instead of an object-array of strings like `Get-Content` does.

```
# Loads xml document

# Get aboslute path
$xmlpath = (Resolve-Path $filepath).Path
# Get xml
$xmlDoc = [xml]([IO.File]::ReadAllLines($xmlpath))
```

An even faster solution would be to drop the casting to xml-document and just parse it as pure text. Still I would avoid `Get-Content` since it is pretty slow. Something like this could work:

```
# Get aboslute path
$xmlpath = (Resolve-Path $filepath).Path

# Get streamreader 
$reader = [io.file]::OpenText($xmlpath)
$currentroot = @()

# Read every line
while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    if ($line.Trim() -eq "<root>") {
        $currentroot.Clear()
        $currentroot += $line
    } else if ($line.Trim() -eq "</root>") {
        $currentroot += $line

        #process root element (by extracting the info from the strings in $currentroot)

        $currentroot.Clear()
    } else {
        $currentroot += $line
    }
}
```